# Finding CSS Selector for selenium test

Tags: html, css, selenium

Could anyone tell me how to correctly find the css selector for the following code. I need to know the css selector and not the xpath as web elements cannot use xpath.

```
<div id="drag" class="dojoDndSource dojoDndTarget dojoDndContainer" style="height:300px;width:250px;font-size:1.2em;border:2px solid #ccc; padding:1em;overflow:auto; " data-dojo-type="dojo.dnd.Source">
<div id="1" class="dojoDndItem" style="padding:.5em;">1</div>
<div id="2" class="dojoDndItem" style="padding:.5em;">2</div>
<div id="3" class="dojoDndItem dojoDndItemAnchor" style="padding:.5em;">3</div>
<div id="99" class="dojoDndItem" style="padding:.5em;">T4</div>
<div id="100" class="dojoDndItem" style="padding:.5em;">T5</div>
```

I wish to select the div with `id="99"`. I've tried using the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".T4"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//input[@id='gbqfq']"));
```

Comment: Why don't you want to go with `ids`?

Comment: `//input[@id='gbqfq']` is XPath, not a CSS selector.

Comment: I'm trying to use a method that used webelements I'm told webelements must be in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've used to locate the element concerned, are both wrong, as explained below:

**1-** `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".T4"));`
Since yo**u have put "." before "T4", it will search for the element having class T4, which is not present**. **"T4",** in fact is the **innerHTML/text** of the element you want to locate.

**2-**`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//input[@id='gbqfq']"));`
 
As **@BoltClock** commented, this is infact an **xpath that you are trying to use with a cssSelector method.**

You can use the **below code to locate the element using xpath, instead**:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[.='T4']"));
```

This will locate the **div element with exact innerHTML/text as 'T4'.**

**Furthermore, You can also use the 'id', provided it is unique and doesn't change dynamically as below:**

**1-** `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='99']"));`
**This will locate the div element with id '99'.**

**2-** `driver.findElement(By.id("99"));`
**This will locate the element with id '99'.**

**3-**`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='99']"));`
**This will also locate the div element with id '99'.**

Answer (score 0):

You are using `XPath` selector with `By.cssSelector()` which is wrong and in css `.` means class and you are trying to pass the text instead. You cannot perform text based search with css selector at this momenet. `XPath` is the best option in such case.

`nth-child()` gives you the ability to find the child element with index if you want to use the `cssSelector`. See [this](https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors)

```
//css walk thorugh with index
.dojoDndItem:nth-child(1)
```

However, I would prefer `xpath` text based search in this case

```
//div[.='1']
//div[.='T4']
```

..etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use `driver.findElement(By.id("99"));` directly or if you want to use css selector, use the one below. you should use `#` if you are trying to get by id and `.` if you getting it by class name. Id selectors are the fastest, so try using id selectors as far as possible.

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#99"));